# Mod_Rewrite Apache Remove 2 Files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am making a social network for my companies intranet. I have successfully been able to utilize htaccess to remove the index.php file from my url, however, there is a "profile.php" file that will allow a user to pull up another users profile. Is there a way to use .htaccess and mod_rewrite to remove both the index.php, and the profile.php?

This is my current htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Again, I want to be able to remove the profile.php as well as the index.php.

Edit: I am running on cPanel's latest version on CentOS Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one answered for over a week, I did this the roundabout way. I redirected all 404 requests to one profile.php excluding all existing files and directories.

I then removed only the profile.php, since index.php is listed as the directoryindex.

Upon completion, profile.php located the profile and displayed the necessary information.